# ClassCastException trying to get OracleConnection from JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data, jdbctemplate, ojdbc

I am creating an `ArrayDescriptor` in order to pass CLOB data to an Oracle function.  I have a class in which I have injected (`@Inject`) a jdbcTemplate...this is an implementation class which has calls out to Oracle. I am creating the `ArrayDescriptor` like:

```
Connection conn = auditJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
ArrayDescriptor keyArryDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("VC_ARR", conn);
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy183 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:105
```

As I stated, I have direct calls in this class to `auditJdbcTemplate.update` that work successfully so I am not sure why it can't return a valid connection object from the template.  I have seen several answers in StackOverflow to get the underlying connection and I have not been able to get that to work.

Comment: FYI, I have tried the OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor as well without success.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe someone find it useful:

```
Connection conn =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```